# ASP.Net Identity using a custom auth provider/service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, rest, asp.net-identity

I am currently developing an ASP.Net MVC web application that requires username and password authentication.  I started looking into using ASP.Net Identity for this however I have a very important requirement, the requirement is that the web application itself has no direct access to any databases, all DB Access is to be exposed to the application via an internal REST service.  This is due to certain security polices we follow.

I realise that ASP.Net identity is capable of supporting external authentication methods but my question is split into 2 parts.

1) How would I configure ASP.Net Identity to use my custom REST service for authentication?

2) How would I go about developing a service that can be used by Identity for authentication ? (what would need to be returned from the service to ASP.Net Identity)

Any help on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Very glad you asked this question. I've tried going through the custom provider stuff but after duplicating the 25-odd methods in my userstore/rolestore models and duplicating them in my remote's webapi controller I discovered the framework doing things like adding an email address to the then-non-existant user. I've basically put it on hold, just doing my weekly google search... :)

Answer (score 5):

I just did what you are asking about. First, as FPar suggested, you need to implement an IUserStore and pass that to your UserManager. Your custom IUserStore will implement the interface, I used Resharper to generate stubs, but instead of using entity framework, you will use HttpClient to make calls to your REST service.

The REST service will have one action on a controller, I called my identityController, for each of the interface methods you actually need. I implemented the userstore, userloginstore and the rolestore, with code for about 10 calls I actually used. The identitycontroller then is what actually accesses the database.

I also retained the fully async pattern, using async REST calls and Database looks, both with and without entity framework. A shortened version of my data access code is in another question here, regarding IUserLoginStore::AddLoginAsync. In that class I actually used the original entityframework implementation of the user store for part of work, and eventually settled on plain (except for async) ado.net for the parts I couldn't make work that way. The tables are simple enough, using your ORM of choice would not take a lot of time.

Good luck!

Comment: I think I see where you are going with that Philip.  Are you saying that on my REST service I will have an Authenticate Action which will take in a username and password as parameters, the REST service will then do the auth at the back end and pass back a Json based result?

Comment: When you wrote "internal REST service" I assumed this was protected by firewall and only accessible by the front end MVC application. Not the case?

Comment: Yes this will be the case Philip.

Comment: Some examples would be very helpful

Answer (score 3):

You want to implement your own [IUserStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613278%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and then pass a reference to the [UserManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Look into the Startup and the IdentityConfig files in the standarad ASP.NET MVC with individual user account authentication, to see, how to use them.

You can look [here](http://identity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/KriaSoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs) for an IUserStore implementation with entity framework. This is a template, you could start from and change it to your needs. However, you don't have to implement all interfaces, just implement the interfaces, you really need. The UserManager is able to handle that (it throws an exception, if you call a method, that requires an interface, that you don't implement.)

Comment: Im not sure if I was clear on my question, I am looking to write an external authentication service that I may use with Identity in a similair way to say Facebook authentication but I have no idea where i would start in writing this type of service and was looking for pointers on this and also how I would configure the Identity framework to use this.

Comment: So does the server have direct access to the database? Because you use the identity framework only serverside. And maybe you want to have a look at the OAuth2 protocol.

Comment: Yes the server that hosts the REST service has access to the database but the actual web application is on a server with no DB access.

Comment: So are you coding the server, that hosts the REST service or are you coding the application?

Comment: If you are saying you want to write an OAuth2 or OpenID provider to be used like you would use facebook or google, you are on your own! Sure it's possible, but seems like overkill for what your stated goal was originally, to separate database access from the web site. That you can do as I outlined, though there were no online examples I could find.

Comment: I went down this road using an example implementation. I was unable to find any concrete information/documentation for what each method in the interfaces was supposed to do? For example, when I started testing the first call made by the framework was to MyUserStore.SetPasswordAsync(user, password). The user didn't exist in the DB yet so my original assumption that I should pull from the DB was wrong. I changed the method (and others like it) to just copy to the passed-in user. That got me past the SetPasswordAsync, but then I got a call to GetPasswordAsync, again before create was called, so ?

Answer (score -1):

These are two excellent articles on this subject:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics